# Parse Query object from pointer reference

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

Hello I wish to query an object from Parse from a pointer reference

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWdBE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4ccd.png

Kindly see images

I have tried this..

```
        let ProfileQuery = Profile.query()
        ProfileQuery!.whereKey("user", equalTo:"GFvQqqBewf")
        ProfileQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(result: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                   print(result) 
                   for summary in result! {
                        print("Summary is .. \(summary["summary"])")
                    }
                }
```

I am hoping to retrive the object (id: NmIGs7FKLu) with the summary print: blahhh..

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
ProfileQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "_User", objectId: "GFvQqqBewf"))
```

Comment: add more explanation to your answer.